# Cannot deregister a script using wp_deregister_script

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I am trying to get rig of the `Disqus` script on my front page, but unfortunately I cannot manage how to do this.

Here is a little story of the steps I've done.

1. Find the script name in the source code files of the plugin

   wp_register_script( 'dsq_count_script', plugins_url(      '/media/js/count.js', **FILE** ) );
      wp_localize_script( 'dsq_count_script', 'countVars', $count_vars );
      wp_enqueue_script( 'dsq_count_script', plugins_url( '/media/js/count.js', **FILE** ) );
2. Add an action for the `wp_print_scripts` hook

   ```
   add_action('wp_print_scripts', array($this, 'deregister_unused_scripts'), 100);
   ```
3. Implement `deregister_unused_scripts` function

   ```
   public function deregister_unused_scripts()
   {
       wp_dequeue_script('dsq_count_script');
       wp_deregister_script('dsq_count_script');
   }
   ```

Still doesn't work.

I also tried another hook

```
    add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'deregister_unused_scripts'), 100);
```

But this didn't help as well, I still get an output in the footer.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var countVars = {"disqusShortname":"myname"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://myurl.net/wp-content/plugins/disqus-comment-system/media/js/count.js?ver=4.7.3'></script>
```

What can be wrong ?

**EDIT**

Here is the action used to register the plugin script.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'dsq_output_footer_comment_js');
```

Comment: At what hook and priority is the script being enqueued?

Comment: @NathanJohnson it is the default one = 10, please see the question update

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When attempting to dequeue a script, we need to hook in after the script is enqueued, but before it's printed. In this case, the Disqus plugin is using the `wp_footer` hook at a priority of 10 to enqueue the scripts. The footer scripts get printed during `wp_footer` at a priority of 20. So we should be able to hook into `wp_footer` at a priority of 11 and dequeue the script.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse_262301_wp_footer', 11 );
function wpse_262301_wp_footer() { 
  wp_dequeue_script( 'dsq_count_script' ); 
}
```

Comment: Awesome !! It works, thank you so much for the answer and explanation

Comment: For anyone else who read the solution too quickly and has set their priority to something greater than 20 (e.g. 999 or 1000 etc.) take special note that the author of the solution explicitly points out that **scripts get printed at a priority of 20**. Wasted 45 minutes because I was too eager to try implementing the solution.

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 1):

add_action('wp_footer') didn't work for me, but it did 'wp_enqueue_scripts':

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_deregister_scripts', 1000 );
 function my_deregister_scripts() {
   wp_deregister_script( 'wdm_script' );
   wp_dequeue_script('wdm_script');
   wp_deregister_script( 'enjoyHint_script' );
   wp_dequeue_script('enjoyHint_script');
}
```